# Httpd service refuse to start because of missing directory under /var/run

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, centos7, service

It looks like my httpd service on centos is not able to create the /var/run/httpd which causes him to refuse to start.

Just to remind you guys /var/run is pointing to /run

```
[root@build72 var]# ls -ld /var/run
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 6 Oct 28  2014 /var/run -> ../run
```

/run is a tempfs (the content is wiped after machine reboot) :

```
[root@build72 var]# mount | grep /run
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=800948k,mode=700)
```

I always have to create the /run/httpd so my httpd service starts else it will f ail :

```
mkdir /run/httpd
```

the output in error_logs is as follows :

```
 [Tue Nov 08 11:10:29.378421 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1370] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
 [Tue Nov 08 11:10:29.378447 2016] [auth_digest:error] [pid 1370] (2)No such file or directory: AH01762: Failed to create shared memory segment on file /run/httpd/authdigest_shm.1370
 [Tue Nov 08 11:10:29.378459 2016] [auth_digest:error] [pid 1370] (2)No such file or directory: AH01760: failed to initialize shm - all nonce-count checking, one-time nonces, and MD5-sess algorithm disabled
 [Tue Nov 08 11:10:29.378462 2016] [:emerg] [pid 1370] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

CentOS Version :

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

httpd version :

```
[root@build72 var]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jul 18 2016 15:30:14
```

selinux is disabled.

Any help with that will be appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: Does /run/httpd exist and is it writable by the apache process?